# Quiero hacer un programa que el el usuario ponga 5 números y que solamente se sumen los nuemros pares

Tags: c++

Generar un programa que solicite 5 números y que solamente se sumen los números pares

Por ejemplo:

5 **6 8** 9 3

Sumatoria de los números pares es: **14**

tengo esto de código pero no se que hacer para que solamente se sumen los numero pares y los impares no

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

main()
{


int num1,num2,num3,num4,num5;
    
printf("introduce numero 1: ");
scanf("%d",&num1);
printf("introduce numero 2: ");
scanf("%d",&num2);
printf("introduce numero 3: ");
scanf("%d",&num3);
printf("introduce numero 4: ");
scanf("%d",&num4);
printf("introduce numero 5: ");
scanf("%d",&num5);
printf("\nel resultado de la suma es:%d",num1+num2+num3+num4+num5);
getch;


return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Ya intentaste buscar como saber si un numero es par o no? Porque es lo unico que hace falta en tu codigo. Verificar que el numero sea par, hacer la suma e imprimir. Si logras comprender esa parte faltante y todavia no logras decifrarlo. Postealo aqui y te echo la mano.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

### Actualización

Existe el operador aritmético `%` (puedes consultar [esta](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html) documentación para más detalles). El funcionamiento de dicho operador está orientado a obtener el valor restante de una división.

Para este caso, necesitas validar que el número sea par, es decir, **divisible por dos**:

```cpp
NUMERO_A_VALIDAR % 2 == 0
```

Al especificar `% 2`, estamos calculando el valor restante de una división por 2. En este caso, si dicho valor restante es **igual a cero**, podemos concluir que el número validado corresponde a un número par. Por lo que la validación apropiada sería:

```cpp
if (NUMERO_A_VALIDAR % 2 == 0) {
  // Usamos el número filtrado según convenga
}
```

La clave está en la comparación `== 0`. La cual será evaluada como **verdadera** sólo cuando `NUMERO_A_VALIDAR` sea par. En rigor, es par cuando la división por 2 retorna un valor **entero** no nulo.

---

### Respuesta anterior:

Lo que requieres utilizar es el operador `%`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <curses.h> // En vez de conio.h, ya que estoy en GNU/Linux

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numbers[5];
    int resultado_numeros_pares = 0;
    
    for (unsigned int index = 0; index < sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(numbers[0]); index++) { // Uso una iteración para no replicar código
        std::cout << "Inserte numero " << std::to_string(index + 1) << ":";
        scanf("%d", &numbers[index]);
        if (numbers[index] % 2 == 0) { // Aqui hacemos la validacion de si es par
          resultado_numeros_pares += numbers[index]; // Y agregamos su valor como suma en dicho caso
        }
    }
    
    std::cout << "Resultado de la suma de los numeros pares: " << resultado_numeros_pares;
    
    getch;

    return 0;
}
```

En la validación `numbers[index] % 2 == 0` estamos verificando que el número sea divisible por 2. La clave está en la comparación `== 0`. `numbers[index] % 2` retorna el valor **restante** de la división, en este caso, por 2.

[Aquí](https://onlinegdb.com/rkluADfRP) está el código como ejemplo ejecutable.

Referencia: https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_operators.asp

Ejemplo de referencia: https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/trycpp.asp?filename=demo_oper_mod

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, pero hay un pequeño error, cuando paso el código a DEV-C, me dice que no existe  #include <curses.h> ya lo cheque en la pagina ejecutable y si funciona muy bien solo que en dev-c no copila por ese error. No se si tu sepas de alguna librería de código que pueda ser compatible

Comment: Sí, por ello puse el comentario en el código, debido a que estoy usando GNU/Linux Fedora. Cito: *En vez de conio.h, ya que estoy en GNU/Linux*.

Comment: Cambia `curses.h` por `conio.h`. Es una modificación para el ejemplo. De otra forma, no hubiese podido hacer un ejemplo funcional. SI esto responde correctamente a la pregunta. No olvides marcarla como respuesta

Comment: vale, pero surge un error al cambiar curses.h por conio.h en `std::cout << "Inserte numero " << std::to_string(index + 1) << ":";`   y me  [Error] 'to_string' no es miembro de 'std'

Comment: Eso ya tiene que ver con cómo tienes configurado tu ambiente de desarrollo. Es importante el uso de `#include <iostream>` y `#include <string>`, además de la línea `using namespace std;`. La cual permite acceder a dicho namespace y sus miembros.

Comment: a vale, yaya, muchas gracias!!!!

Comment: Si bien la respuesta es correcta, @KBeDev, hacerle los deberes a la gente no está muy bien visto por aquí. Muchísimo menos aún cuando el autor de la pregunta todavía no ha ni *mostrado un intento de hacer lo que pide él mismo*. Te recomiendo que la próxima vez que vayas a responder a una pregunta que parezca un ejercicio, en vez de dar la respuesta correcta completa simplemente intentes ***guiar*** al autor para que la encuentre él mismo, pues es la única manera en que aprenderá a buscarse la vida y pelearse con el código, que es una de las bases que más falta hacen a un programador!

Comment: @Benito-B Acepto la recomendación. Quizá fue un error ser demasiado extensivo al momento de explicar, lo que dio como resultado una respuesta/solución que favorece el copy-paste. Pero fui flexible debido a la naturaleza "principiante" de la pregunta. Actualizaré la respuesta para dar una orientación más fundamental sobre la pregunta.

Comment: No es necesario que se peleen, al contrario yo se que no me la ibas a poner fácil, soy nuevo en esto y por suerte si me salió el código , solo fue cuestión de borrar una parte del código para que me saliera; Pero de en verdad muchas gracias!!